# Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, gac

I am trying to put a build together on TFS that starts another build within a different TFS collection by using a PowerShell script that a coworker wrote and had working previously. However, this script was written and tested on VS 2015 Professional and I am using 2017 Enterprise. When I go to run this script in my build I get the following error:

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]
```

when it hits this:

```
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)
```

I have looked through the .dlls in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer` but cannot find this dll (maybe specific to Professional 2015?)

How would I go  about solving this issue? From my research it seems like I need to add the dll to the GAC, but not sure which dll to add. If this dll is not associated with Enterprise 2017, how would I change this line to work with my version?

Answer (score 4):

The object model client libraries are not in GAC.

Add the dll to load by `Add-Type` cmdlet like below: (In your scenario you need to add `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll`)

```
$visualStudiopath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer'
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-type -path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"
```

Comment: I don't know about OP, but I'm in the exact scenario they described. I've tested your solution, but the system is still unable to find Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory. Is there another step that might help resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Install the NuGet package [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient).

Comment: I'm working on an offline machine, do you know a resource that I could use to install it offline?

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](https://github.com/sameer-kumar/adhoc-posh/blob/master/QueueTfsBuild.ps1) script helps. No binaries needed with this approach.

You can customize this per your requirements.

P.S. It works for TFS 2017.1

Answer (score 0):

Only VS 2015 assemblies helped me in the same case...
Order of adding is also very important!

```
    try
{

    $visualStudiopath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer'

    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.ControlsCore.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-type -path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$visualStudiopath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"
}
catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException]
{
   Write-Host "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
   Write-Host "StackTrace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)"
   Write-Host "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"
}
```