# Cannot convert value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type"

Tags: powershell, tfsbuild

I am trying to build a tfs workstation using PowerShell, but I've become stuck.

In my code are the lines

> $teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundationClient.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsServer)
>
> $ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type] "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore")

I got those lines from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56981793/3025685) on another question I recently asked. The answer solved the problem I had then, but unfortunately that second line gets an exception when trying to convert the string to Type. Specifically, the error I get is:

> Cannot convert the "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".

I know that the GetService function I'm using expects a System.Type parameter. I also haven't found a means to convert a System.String object into a System.Type object strictly through PowerShell.

So, how do I either fix this or get around this problem?

Comment: Does `[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore] | Get-Member` return anything?

Comment: It does not. It gets a TypeNotFound exception.

Comment: Have you added the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll` assembly to that PowerShell session?

Comment: That was the problem. Would you like to post it as answer?

Comment: I posted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add an assembly to gain access to the `[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore]` type. Assuming you are in the directory that contains the assembly file, you can run the following in your current PowerShell session.

```
Add-Type -Path ".\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
```