# Cannot find [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory] even after using Add-Type

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am trying to automate the mapping of a tfs collection to a local workspace for users who may not have administrator privileges.

Currently, I'm trying to use

> $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationFactory]::GetServer($tfsServer)

to get the TFS server. However, this line of code causes an error saying

> Unable to find type [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]

I have included the following line:

> Add-Type -Path "$path.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"

earlier in the script.

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56976206/3025685) earlier, but I was still putting relevant DLLs into the GAC for that question. I am no longer doing that, as manipulation of the GAC typically require admin rights, and I cannot guarantee that users of my script will have those rights.

Now that I have decided not to add the DLLs to the GAC, the code that was working now fails.

Is there a way to get the TFS server without using the GAC or anything else requiring admin rights, and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: Is your `Add-Type` line a typo? I would think it should be `"$path\Microsoft.Team` not `"$path.Microsoft.Team`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code like this:

```
    $TfsAssembliesPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.Interactive.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$TfsAssembliesPath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll"
[string]$tfsCollectionUrl="TFS collection URL"
    [string]$tfsTeamProjectName="team project"

    $teamProjectCollection=[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($tfsCollectionUrl)
    $ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore")
    $proj = $ws.Projects[$tfsTeamProjectName]

    $wit = $proj.WorkItemTypes["Task"]

    #Create a new work item of that type
    $workitem = $wit.NewWorkItem()

    $workItem.Title = "Sample Task Title 3"
    $workItem.Description = "Sample Description"
    $workitem.AreaPath = $tfsTeamProjectName
    $workitem.IterationPath = $tfsTeamProjectName

    $workItem.Save()
```